# Spring Boot RestController testing returns 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to test my code (Spring-Boot project) of a RestController, but I always get 404. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
@RestController("/service")
public class ServiceInteractionController {

@Autowired
private PairingService pairingService;

@GetMapping("/registered/{sensorId}")
public ResponseEntity isSensorRegistered(@PathVariable String sensorId) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(pairingService.isSensorRegistered(sensorId));
}
```

}

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ServiceInteractionController.class)
public class ServiceInteractionControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private PairingService pairingService;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    Mockito.when(pairingService.isSensorRegistered(TestConstants.TEST_SENSOR_ID))
            .thenReturn(true);
}

@Test
public void testIsSensorRegistered() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("service/registered/{sensorId}", TestConstants.TEST_SENSOR_ID))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

}

The result always looks like this:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = service/registered/test123Id
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

What am I doing wrong? I already tried to initialize mockmvc directly in setUp method with standaloneSetup() and I have also used @SpringBootTest combined with @AutoConfigureMockMvc.

Does anyone have some useful hints? I use spring boot 2.1.4.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a leading `/` in your URL.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen that, but it still does not work and shows the same error, 404 instead of 200. Do you have some other hints?

Comment: Then your URL isn't the one you expect it to be. Do you have a prefix registered in your `application.properties`?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I fixed it, the paranthesis behind `@RestController` are not the right place for the REST path, I have to use `@RequestMapping` for that.

Comment: Yes indeed. The `@RestController` can only be given a name it will not be used for the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you miss the "/" before the service/registered/{sensorId}?

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("service/registered/{sensorId}", TestConstants.TEST_SENSOR_ID))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me this hint, but it still does not work. There is still the same AssertionError because I expect 200 and get 404. Do you have some other advices?

Comment: can you access it direct from browser or curl, and share the result

Answer (score -3):

Try changing this function to read:

```
@PathVariable 
@Test
public void testIsSensorRegistered(@PathVariable sensorId ) throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("service/registered/{sensorId}", TestConstants.TEST_SENSOR_ID))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed and why it solves the problem?